# Error when trying to create a rally item using rally_api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rally

I tried to save a rally description in between angle braces but the value is not getting saved. Ex< the real description >this value(without spacing between the angle brackets and the alphabets) is getting saved as empty. Can somebody tell me how to overcome this problem. I am using ruby gem rally_api (1.1.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the '<' and '>' needs to be replaced by '&lt;' and '&gt;'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me the reason behind it please